# Need help troubleshooting DB connection

Tags: database

I'm moving a craft install from a development to production server and am getting this error:

```
ERROR ERROR
Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php.
```

I've triple checked the db credentials and permissions and everything is correct. Here's my db.php file:

```
<?php

// uncommenting this gives me a 'connected okay' so I know that the credentials are correct.
// if ($con=mysqli_connect("localhost","thandtho_db","*********","thandtho_production")) // {
//  die('connected okay');
// } else {
//  die('couldn\'t connect');
// } 

/**
 * Database Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's database configuration settings go in here.
 * You can see a list of the default settings in craft/app/etc/config/defaults/db.php
 */

// Import your local config settings
require( 'config.local.php' );

return array(
    '*'=> array(
        // Database Info
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
    // Production Domain
    '9thandthomas.com' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'thandtho_db',
        'password' => '***********',
        'database' => 'thandtho_production'
    ),
    ),
    // Dev
    '9thandthomas.transomco.com' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'ninththomas_dev',
        'password' => '4iJoi58@',
        'database' => 'ninththomas_dev'
    ),
    // Local
    // Needs to be placed after production since subdomain
    // is similar to production domain name.
    $localConfig['envUrl'] =>  array (
        'server' => $localDatabase['server'],
        'user' => $localDatabase['user'],
        'password' => $localDatabase['password'],
        'database' => $localDatabase['database'],
    )
);
```

************************** ANSWER **************************

I moved the database details from beneath the * and it worked.

db.php now looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Database Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's database configuration settings go in here.
 * You can see a list of the default settings in craft/app/etc/config/defaults/db.php
 */

// Import your local config settings
require( 'config.local.php' );

return array(
    '*'=> array(
        // Database Info
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
    ),
    // Production Domain
    '9thandthomas.com' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'thandtho_db',
        'password' => 'wR39fy2!k',
        'database' => 'thandtho_production'
    ),
    // Dev
    '9thandthomas.transomco.com' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'ninththomas_dev',
        'password' => '4iJoi58@',
        'database' => 'ninththomas_dev'
    ),
    // Local
    // Needs to be placed after production since subdomain
    // is similar to production domain name.
    $localConfig['envUrl'] =>  array (
        'server' => $localDatabase['server'],
        'user' => $localDatabase['user'],
        'password' => $localDatabase['password'],
        'database' => $localDatabase['database'],
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue where my '*' was being chosen all of the time, meaning all my environments used the same DB details.

Possibly try splitting it up, and not have a '*' for your DB details, for any environment?

Comment: No problem! Threw me off first time as well :) Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that really was your db.php, you have `'9thandthomas.com'` *inside* the `*` array, not *beneath* it:

```
return array(
  '*' => array(
    ...
    '9thandthomas.com' => array( ... )
  ),
  // '9thandthomas.com' SHOULD BE HERE
  ...
)
```

Comment: Yeah Marion, that was the problem. Not sure how it got where it was...